# Google Apps Script public dev link requiring signin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-authentication

I'm trying to get into WebApp development with Google Apps Scripts.

```
const doPost = e => {
  Logger.log(e)
}
```

I've published it, and when I browse, I get the page.  I can browse to the weblink ... but if I browse to it in an incognito tab, it takes me to a Google signin page, instead.  In this project, I need an unauthenticated device to be able to make POST and GET requests (just to be able to pass data in and out).

The deployment is listed to run as me, and to be visible to 'Anyone' (not just anyone with a Google account, which is one of the options).  This behaviour is the same for the deployment link and the /dev link.

Comment: try doGet(e)  or doPost(e)

Comment: @Cooper - I tried changing it over to the old style funcs, just in case... but it still doesn't let me load the page without being signed in.

Comment: development links (`/dev`) can accessed only by user with edit access to the script, so you have to login.
Read more [here][1].

  [1]: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#test_a_web_app_deployment